# Third Party library requires different version of the same DLL my application does

Tags: c++, dll, conflict, tbb, name-conflict

I'm writing an application that uses both Intel's TBB library, and an API from a company called Maplink, which also uses TBB. The problem is that both my application and the Maplink API want to load TBB.dll from the directory containing my application's binary. The version of TBB.dll that Maplink provided with their API differs from the one my application requires, and they can't both co-exist in the application's executable directory. Do I have any option here other than statically linking TBB into my application so that it doesn't try to load the wrong version of TBB.dll that the Maplink API is using?

Comment: Doesn't the newer version of tbb.dll work for both?

Comment: Intel does [not want to solve this problem](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/286809) it is yours to deal with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you may put the newer version of tbb.dll into your application directory, and it should work properly for both the application and the 3rd party library it uses. For example, the recent version - TBB 4.2 - is binary compatible with old versions back to TBB 2.0.

Answer (score 3):

In the real world, it is a bad idea to mix different versions of the same DLL. You should really try and get your platform aligned. It is not called package hell for nothing.

That being said, it is very much up to the `TBB.dll` if it allows for multiple versions at once.  You might be able to statically link your code against your version of TBB, but in doing so you will need to make sure the statically linked-in symbols are not dynamically visible (a compiler collection dependant linker option). The code that you have that depends on TBB must probably also be linked in a separate linker step from the one that includes linking to maplink. And the application will need to be linked without relinking against `TBB.dll`.

At least that is how it could work for `so` files in Linux.